# Are FxPlugs sandboxed inside Final Cut Pro X?

Tags: plugins, sandbox, finalcut

I'm working with plugins for Final Cut Pro X and need to send data out to another program. So far I was able to do it by using [`NSDistributedNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDistributedNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but that is *not supposed to work*. According to its Apple Developer page:

> Important: Sandboxed apps can send notifications only if they do not contain a dictionary. If the sending application is in an App Sandbox, notificationInfo must be nil.

Final Cut Pro X is sold in the Mac App Store and everything I've seen points to it being sandboxed. Does anyone know if there's a bug with FCPX's sandbox, with the distributed notification center, or are FxPlugs run outside the sandbox? I rather not have critical code rely on something that works but isn't supposed to.

My notification sending code in the FxPlug:

```
NSDistributedNotificationCenter* dist = [NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"First value", @"key1",
                     @"Second value from FCPX", @"key2", @"Third & final value", @"3key3", nil];

[dist postNotificationName:@"FCPX plugin"
                    object:@"SFPCommApp"
                  userInfo:dict];
```

And receiving code in the other app:

```
m_center = [NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[m_center addObserver:self 
             selector:@selector(GetNotification:) 
                 name:nil 
               object:listenTo];

// in GetNotification
NSString *notifString = [notification description];
NSString *dispString = @"Got notification from Final Cut Pro X";
dispString = [dispString stringByAppendingString:notifString];
// dispString displayed in a dialog
```

It works in the Xcode debugger and entirely outside Xcode (both launched from Finder). Also, I need to support 10.6 so can't use XPC.

Ideas on other methods to send data out from an FxPlug? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you download the latest FxPlug SDK (3.0) from [Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action), it includes updated examples for building an FxPlug with an XPC. Final Cut Pro X is not yet sandboxed, but it seems likely that it will be in the future.

Comment: A quick update to this answer 2 years on, and FCP X is still not run in a sandbox (checked using the Sandbox column in Activity Monitor).